# CefSharp WpfControl and rendering to image

Tags: cefsharp, cefsharp.offscreen

We want to show a webpage in a chromium based browser within a wpf application.
The website that is displayed within the browser should also be shown on another screen but without interaction.
I want to combine the cefsharp wpf browser control and the cefsharp offscreen rendering.

Can I use one chromium instance for displaying the page with interactions in wpf and export the current visible website as an image?

Thank you and best regards,

Simon

Comment: Yes you can capture the output, have a look at the source, `OnPaint`.

Comment: If you add your comment as a answear i can mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 5):

Thank you amatiland, it indeed works with the OnPaint Method or Event.

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Browser.Paint += Browser_Paint;
    }

    void Browser_Paint(object sender, CefSharp.Wpf.PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Bitmap newBitmap = new Bitmap(e.Width, e.Height, 4 * e.Width, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb, e.Buffer);

        var aPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures), "TestImageCefSharpQuant.png");
        newBitmap.Save(aPath);
    }
```

XAML

```
    <wpf:ChromiumWebBrowser x:Name="Browser" Address="www.google.com"></wpf:ChromiumWebBrowser>
```

Comment: Just as a quick follow up if the `Bitmap` contains any sort of transparency then you'd need to use `PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb`

Comment: @amaitland do you have an example with PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb? When i just change the Format the Bitmap is grayscales and the bitmap size properties not the same as on screen

Comment: @KevinV Look in the project source on GitHub. The OffScreen implementation uses PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb internally.